# GRUB/BURG hates Windows 7

Tags: 11.04, grub2, windows-7, bootloader, burg

Every time I try to access my Windows 7 partition from BURG, I get a "required device is not installed" error with an error code of 0xc000000f. The same thing happens in normal GRUB.

I am on Natty and on a Dell system (the BURG wiki mentioned something about Dells). My other partition is Windows 7 SP1 and was installed before Natty.

Answer (score 1):

While ubuntu doesn't really hate windows it makes it harder to play with some times.

I recommend reading the listing below to help you with dual booting.

http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-11-04-with-windows-7/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.